# How to sort array of objects by value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have this kind of array of object:

```
[
  {variable: "contactPhone", title: "Phone", type: "text"},
  {variable: "contactName", title: "Name", type: "text"}
]
```

Each time on click I'm dynamically adding new objects in array. It is actually a clone one of the objects depending on which one user clicked.
So I need to sort them like this, contactPhone to be always on top, contactName on the bottom:

```
[
  {variable: "contactPhone", title: "Phone", type: "text"},
  {variable: "contactPhone", title: "Phone", type: "text"},
  {variable: "contactPhone", title: "Phone", type: "text"},
  {variable: "contactName", title: "Name", type: "text"},
  {variable: "contactName", title: "Name", type: "text"},
]
```

here what I'm trying to do, but it doesnt work. Any ideas ?

```
addNewInput(i) {
    const { data, index } = this.state
    let cloned = { ...data[index].variables[i] }
    const newData = this.state.data
    newData[index].variables.push(cloned)
    data[index].variables.sort((a, b) => (a.variable === b.variable ? 1 : -1))
    this.setState({
      data: newData,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why do you swap the elements if they are the same (`a.variable === b.variable ? 1 : -1`)?

Comment: There are 3 possible conditions in `sort()`, not 2

Comment: Try sorting using:

    data[index].sort((a,b)=> a.variable.localeCompare(b.variable))

Take a look at : https://plnkr.co/edit/sAG9gdSgILLKs7JkvjSf?p=preview